# Calling into java wildcard generic method from Scala

Tags: scala

How does one invoke the following java method from scala?

```
public static Config parseMap(Map<String, ? extends Object> values,
        String originDescription) {
```

I have attempted to invoke it as follows:

```
 val SAMPLE_PROPS_MAP : Map[String,AnyRef] = Map("hiveSaveFreq" -> new java.lang.Long(10L), "aggSeconds" -> new java.lang.Long(3))
 val props = ConfigFactory.parseMap(SAMPLE_PROPS_MAP,"props"))
```

However Intellij complains:

```
   Cannot resolve symbol parseMap
```

To ensure this were not other issues (e.g. incorrect version of libraries):

```
 val props = ConfigFactory.parseMap(null,"props"))
```

works fine.  Also, the intellisense bubble does confirm the signature as being shown above (having Map).

However Intellij complains:

So then what is the Scala equivalent to the **? extends Object**

Comment: `Cannot resolve symbol parseMap` means it cannot see it. You are probably missing some import or classpath entry. If it was not compatible, the message would be like `method parseMap cannot be applied to blablabla`

Comment: No, that is not the way ij scala plugin works.  I can put in a "null" in place of the map and it is fine. I have also updated the OP to reflect this info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not on the **? extends Object** type boundary declaration but rather on the Map definition. The signature you have is:
`public static Config parseMap(**java.util.Map**<String, ? extends Object> values, String originDescription)`
and you are passing it a `scala.collection.immutable.Map`

You need to convert your scala map to a java map, either by creating a java map "by hand" or using the facilities in the scala API:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val SamplePropsMap : Map[String,AnyRef] = Map("hiveSaveFreq" -> new java.lang.Long(10L), "aggSeconds" -> new java.lang.Long(3))
val props = ConfigFactory.parseMap(SamplePropsMap.asJava,"props"))
```

(note: The implicit methods in JavaConverters are the recommended way to deal with java-scala conversions, by using `javaCollection.asScala` and `scalaCollection.asJava`.  Also note that in Scala, the convention for 'constants' is camel-case starting with a capital. e.g. CamelCase)

Comment: I can never keep JavaConverters and JavaConversions straight in my mind: I had answered my own question with the JavaConversions instead, but am receptive to JavaConverters being preferred.

Comment: @javadba actually your explicit usage is OK. `JavaConverters` are preferred over `JavaConversions` when using implicits. With `JavaConverters` you still have the explicit `asScala` or `asJava` that prevents the unexpected conversions you may have with `import JavaConversions._`

Answer (score 0):

The Map needs to be converted to java format, as follows:

```
import collection.JavaConversions._
val props = ConfigFactory.parseMap(mapAsJavaMap(SAMPLE_PROPS_MAP))
```